# Relate 2 tables in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in a database. One is for product data, and the other is for the images of the products. I have to set up an slider in the index of my page, and there will go specific images (like products with 50% discount, or sth like that). I'll make a query to my product table in my database, to get the id of the product that are on sale

```
$query1="SELECT id FROM products WHERE price<'100'";
$query2=mysql_query($query1);
$idSales=mysql_fetch_array($query2);
```

So, now i have an array with the id's of the products that I'm interested in, and here comes the trouble. How can I deal with that array that `mysql_fetch_array` returned to me? How can I make the query to the `images` table (
in that table I have the id of the corresponding product, so I've to match one with the other)

Comment: show your table structure or use join

Comment: table "products"

id
category
model
color

table "images"
id
idProduct
imageName

Comment: Use `Join` - `select b.imageName from products a inner join images b on b.idProduct = a.id`

Comment: Thank you! I used join and it worled perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join these two tables to get images of the products.
Run this query

```
  SELECT i.`imageName`
  FROM products p INNER JOIN images i
  ON p.`id`=i.`idProduct`
  WHERE p.price<100
```

Comment: @LucasDallaRizza You're welcome. Please mark it right

Answer (score 1):

You can try running multiple inline queries.For performance considerations I would not suggest doing this but it can get the job done with less number of records:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    //now create a new query 
    $img_query = "SELECT * FROM ... where id=".$id;
    //run query and process results
    $img_result = mysql_fetch_array($img_query)
        //work with image related results here
}
```

You can also create a sql array and run the query after the while loop is finished.

Comment: Thnk you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use subrequest

```sql
SELECT * FROM images WHERE product_id IN (SELECT id FROM products WHERE price < '100')
```